# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setVisibility(int)' on a null object

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have 3 buttons on my layout 1 visible and 2 invisible at the time when the app is open,
when I click the 1st visible button it's open the camera to click the picture after the picture was clicked the picture was displayed at an ImageView on that same layout. After the picture was displayed at that ImageView I want to make the 2 invisible buttons visible and the 1 visible button invisible but when I try to do this I gating this error.

**here is my XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="30dp"
    tools:context=".Front_Scan">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Scan Front Side"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/yellow"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/background"
        app:cardCornerRadius="22dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Image_id_front"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/id_front" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Front_imgCapture_again"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/flag_transparent"
        android:text="Scan Again"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/yellow"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <android.widget.Button
        android:id="@+id/imgCapture_front"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style_ylo"
        android:text="Scan Now"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <android.widget.Button
        android:id="@+id/front_next"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style_ylo"
        android:text="Next Step"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="next"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZFvJ.jpg)

**here is my java class Code**

```
public class Front_Scan extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final int PERMISSION_CODE = 1000;
    private static final int IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE = 1001;
    Button frontImgCap;
    Button frontImgCapAgain;
    Button frontNext;

    ImageView frontImg;

    Uri image_uri;

    private int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 101;
    private String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{"android.permission.CAMERA",
            "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};
    AutoFitTextureView textureView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_front_scan);
        frontImg = findViewById(R.id.Image_id_front);
        frontImgCap = findViewById(R.id.imgCapture_front);
        frontImgCapAgain = findViewById(R.id.imgCapture_again);
        frontNext = findViewById(R.id.front_next);

        frontImgCap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //if system os is >= marshmallow, request runtime permission

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ||
                            checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        //permission not enable, request it
                        String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                        //show popup to request permissions
                        requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                    } else {
                        //permission already given
                        openCamera();

                    }
                } else {
                    //system os < marshmallow
                    openCamera();

                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void openCamera() {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From the camera");
        image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        //Camera intent
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE);

    }

    public void next(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Front_Scan.this, back_scan.class);
        Front_Scan.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {

            case PERMISSION_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    openCamera();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @NonNull Intent data) {
        //called when image was captured from camera
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            frontImg.setImageURI(image_uri);
           //geting error at this line//
 frontImgCapAgain.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            frontImgCap.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            frontNext.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think You should change something in Your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Try adding the `singleTop` attribute to the `Front_Scan <activity>`. I've encountered a similar problem once and the attribute helped because, as the docs say:

> If, when starting the activity, there is already an instance of the same activity class in the foreground that is interacting with the user, then re-use that instance.

So the code fragment in Your case should look like this:

```xml
<activity
            android:name=".Front_Scan"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            ...>
        ...
</activity>
```